# Plot difference between two Plotly hexbin maps

Tags: python, plotly

I've seen posts relating to plotting the difference between two hexbin maps in matplotlib. I couldn't find anything executing the same process but for Plotly hexbin map box plots. If I have two separate hexbin subplots `(t, y)`, is it possible to produce a single plot that subtracts the difference between `t` and `y`?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data = pd.DataFrame({
   'Cat': ['t','y','y','t','t','t','t','y','y','y','t','y'],
   'LAT': [5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7],
   'LON': [10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12],
   })

data = pd.concat([data]*5)

df_t = data[data['Cat'] == 't']
df_y = data[data['Cat'] == 'y']

fig = make_subplots(
    rows = 2, 
    cols = 1, 
    subplot_titles = ('t', 'y'),
    specs = [[{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}], [{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}]],
    vertical_spacing = 0.05,
    horizontal_spacing = 0.05
    )

fig2 = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame=df_t,
                           lat="LAT", lon="LON",
                           nx_hexagon=5,
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={"color": "Point Count"},
                           mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                          )

fig3 = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame=df_y,
                           lat="LAT", lon="LON",
                           nx_hexagon=5,
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={"color": "Point Count"},
                           mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                          )


fig.add_trace(fig2.data[0], row=1,col=1)
fig.update_mapboxes(zoom=4, style='carto-positron')
fig.add_trace(fig3.data[0], row=2,col=1)
fig.update_mapboxes(zoom=4, style='carto-positron')

fig.update_layout(height=600, margin=dict(t=20,b=0,l=0,r=0))
fig.show()
```

intended output:

The bottom left bin for `t` has 15 points, while `y` has 5. So this will total 10. The middle bin has 10 points for both so will result in 0. The top right has 5 for `t` and 15 for `y`, coming to -10. But I'll set `vmin` to 0 to ensure no negative values.

[image]

Edit 2:

If I alter the input data with different size arrays and include min_count = 1 as a parameter, I return an error.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
       'Cat': ['t','y','y','t','t','t','t','y','y','y','t','y','y'],
       'LAT': [5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,8],
       'LON': [10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12,8],
       })

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) /var/folders/bf/09nyl3td65j2lty5m7138ndw0000gn/T/ipykernel_78237/2142200526.py in <module>
     47 
     48 fig = go.Figure(fig2)
---> 49 fig.data[0]['z'] = (fig2.data[0]['z'] - fig3.data[0]['z']).clip(min=0)
     50 cmax, cmin = max(fig.data[0]['z']), min(fig.data[0]['z'])
     51 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)
```

Comment: could we create another figure factory hexbin mapbox with the difference between `df_t` and `df_y`? also is the intended output a single figure, or an additional figure below the two current figures?

Comment: Another figure is fine. The intended output is a single figure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since plotly determines the counts within each hexbin when creating the figure, you'll need to access the count data inside both `fig2` and `fig3`.

Here is the array as it's stored inside `fig2.data[0]['z']`:

```
array([15.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  5.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0., 10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

We can set `fig` to be a copy of fig2, create a new array by taking the difference between the count arrays from fig2 and fig3 (and clipping it at 0), and set `fig.data[0]['z']` to this new array. You will also want to update the minimum and maximum values of the `colorbar` accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data = pd.DataFrame({
   'Cat': ['t','y','y','t','t','t','t','y','y','y','t','y'],
   'LAT': [5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7],
   'LON': [10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12],
   })

data = pd.concat([data]*5)

df_t = data[data['Cat'] == 't']
df_y = data[data['Cat'] == 'y']

# fig = make_subplots(
#     rows = 2, 
#     cols = 1, 
#     subplot_titles = ('t', 'y'),
#     specs = [[{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}], [{"type": "choroplethmapbox"}]],
#     vertical_spacing = 0.05,
#     horizontal_spacing = 0.05
#     )

fig2 = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame=df_t,
                           lat="LAT", lon="LON",
                           nx_hexagon=5,
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={"color": "Point Count"},
                           mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                          )

fig3 = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame=df_y,
                           lat="LAT", lon="LON",
                           nx_hexagon=5,
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={"color": "Point Count"},
                           mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                          )

fig = go.Figure(fig2)
fig.data[0]['z'] = (fig2.data[0]['z'] - fig3.data[0]['z']).clip(min=0)
cmax, cmin = max(fig.data[0]['z']), min(fig.data[0]['z'])

fig.update_mapboxes(zoom=6, style='carto-positron')
fig.update_layout(height=600, margin=dict(t=20,b=0,l=0,r=0))
fig.update_coloraxes(cmax=cmax, cmin=cmin)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Update: in a situation where `fig2.data[0]['z']` and `fig3.data[0]['z']` are arrays of different lengths, you'll need to pad the shorter array. I am making the assumption that the padding values are zero, and that we will calculate the differences in the same manner.

Using your edited sample data, we get that fig2.data[0]['z'] is `array([15.,  5., 10.])` and fig3.data[0]['z'] is `array([10., 15.,  5.,  5.])`. So we pad array([15.,  5., 10.]) with 0s to match the length of the other array meaning we use `array([15.,  5., 10., 0.])`. I've added some code which pads the shorter array, then computes the difference and clips negative values the same way as before.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# data = pd.DataFrame({
#    'Cat': ['t','y','y','t','t','t','t','y','y','y','t','y'],
#    'LAT': [5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7],
#    'LON': [10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12],
#    })

data = pd.DataFrame({
       'Cat': ['t','y','y','t','t','t','t','y','y','y','t','y','y'],
       'LAT': [5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6,7,8],
       'LON': [10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12,10,11,12,8],
       })

data = pd.concat([data]*5)

df_t = data[data['Cat'] == 't']
df_y = data[data['Cat'] == 'y']

fig2 = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame=df_t,
                           lat="LAT", lon="LON",
                           nx_hexagon=5,
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={"color": "Point Count"},
                           mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                           min_count=1
                          )

fig3 = ff.create_hexbin_mapbox(data_frame=df_y,
                           lat="LAT", lon="LON",
                           nx_hexagon=5,
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={"color": "Point Count"},
                           mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                           min_count=1,
                          )

fig = go.Figure(fig2)
fig2_values, fig3_values = fig2.data[0]['z'], fig3.data[0]['z']

## we pad whichever figure has fewer z values
if len(fig2_values) < len(fig3_values):
   pad_length = len(fig3_values) - len(fig2_values)
   fig2_values = np.pad(fig2_values, (0, pad_length), 'constant')
elif len(fig2_values) > len(fig3_values):
   pad_length = len(fig2_values) - len(fig3_values)
   fig3_values = np.pad(fig3_values, (0, pad_length), 'constant')
else:
   pass

fig.data[0]['z'] = (fig2_values - fig3_values).clip(min=0)
cmax, cmin = max(fig.data[0]['z']), min(fig.data[0]['z'])

fig.update_mapboxes(zoom=6, style='carto-positron')
fig.update_layout(height=600, margin=dict(t=20,b=0,l=0,r=0))
fig.update_coloraxes(cmax=cmax, cmin=cmin)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to subset the data and plot min_count as 1 if the two arrays are different sizes. I'll add an edit 2.

Comment: @jonboy if you have a situation where two hexbins aren't the same size, you will need to pad the array of the one that has less length. i'll update my answer with some more specific details